# What's the probability that of the first 6 phones serviced, we service 2 of each type?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$15$ phones are being serviced, $5$ of each type. The question is, what's the probability that of the first $6$ phones serviced, we service $2$ of each type?

I thought this would be $\dfrac{\dbinom62\dbinom42\dbinom22}{\dbinom{15}6}$, but this is wrong. The back of the book tells me the answer is $0.1998$. What's wrong with my logic here, and what should the correct answer be?

Edit: my logic with the numerator is that, of the $6$ phones we have, we choose $2$ of them as the first type, thus $\dbinom62$. That leaves $4$ choices left, of which another $2$ are the next type, and then $\dbinom22$ for what's left. The denominator simply reflects the fact that we've chosen to look at $6$ phones out of $15$.

Comment: We cannot tell you what is wrong with your logic, unless you tell use what your logic is. How did you come up with the answer of (6C2 * 4C2 * 2C2) / 15C6? Please answer not with a comment, but by clicking `Edit` below your post.

Comment: All that $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$ is deciding on is which of the six positions are occupied by phones of the first type, of the second type, and of the third without taking into account what the serial numbers are on the phones or who owned them etc... Note that the denominator treated the fifteen phones as all being distinct.  Your numerator should have done the same.  Further, your numerator treats order as relevant but your denominator does not.  The first mistake puts your answer off by a factor of $5^3\times 4^3$.  The second mistake by another $6!$

Comment: [Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).  $\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{15}{6}} = \frac{200}{1001}\approx 0.1998$

Comment: Why 5C2 rather than 6C2? More specifically, where did the 5 cone from?

Comment: @DanW: In order to satisfy the condition, you must **choose** $2$ of the $5$ phones of type I, $2$ of the $5$ phones of type II, and $2$ of the $5$ phones of type III.  This is out of a space where you choose $6$ of the $15$ phones altogether.

Comment: OHHH of course, yes that makes more sense, thank you!